# AutoCompleteTextView for RTL in Android

Tags: android

I have an autocomplete textview which is working perfect with english but I want to to use it for farsi/persian language.

Does android support it?. The data in the autocomplete is got from the db. Can somebody please help me to make this work?

please help

cheers
Zolf

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061091/how-can-i-support-farsi-persian-text-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813) , it is about how to support Persi  / Arabic and other language in different versions in Android ,

Comment: I have seen that befoe. I want to know how autocomplete will filter the workds when i type in persian

Comment: please help,i need this badly

Comment: i don't know how to filter autocomplete for persian language, and i've never try it  , try to add it as an issue or question in google group android , and you will get help from there, and from my side, i will search for a solution for your problem incha Allah

Comment: Have you written your own Custom Filtering ArrayAdapter ? The question is a bit unclear in terms of details. In case u have already written your custome filter, try putting more logs in the getFilter() function to check  how the function is behaving. or else copy paste your code here for us to detect the problem. In case you need help in writing your own custom filtering array adapter you can follow the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492214/custom-filtering-arrayadapter-in-listview?rq=1    .

Comment: I am just guessing here as I haven't seen the Android provided code of the filter whether it supports Persian,Arabic etc. I would have tried writing my own filter to get more control over the filtering process.

Comment: no i have not, i was in the impression that the AutocompleteTextView will work for RTL language as is it is for english,french language. please i am new to android and I will appreciate if you can guide me to implement my requirements.

Comment: please help,i will appreciate